# Under the sum and multiplication symbols the statement.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For $m=1$ we have $\binom{k_2}{k_1}$;

For $m=2$ we have $\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}$;

For $m=3$ we have $\binom{k_4}{k_3}\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}$.
We continue this way.

I want to write for each $m$ the following way:

$\textbf{Example}:$ How can we write the following statement under the sum and multiplication symbol? 
We can also use sub-indices if necessary.

$$\binom{k_2}{k_1}+\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}+\binom{k_4}{k_3}\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}=\sum\displaystyle  \prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}$$

I couldn't index the summation symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $\sum_{m = 1}^3$:
$$
\binom{k_2}{k_1}+\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}+\binom{k_4}{k_3}\binom{k_3}{k_2}\binom{k_2}{k_1}=\sum_{m = 1}^3  \prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}
$$
You can see this by inserting $m = 1, 2$ or $3$ into $\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}$ and writing out what you get. For instance, inserting $m = 2$ gives
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{2}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i} = \binom{k_2}{k_1}\binom{k_3}{k_2}
$$
which is the second term from the sum above. Similarily, $m = 1$ gives the first term, and $m = 3$ gives the third term.

Comment: For $m=1$, $\displaystyle \sum_{m = 1}^{3}  \prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}=3\binom{k_2}{k_1}$

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 No. I said "inserting $m = 1, 2$ or $3$ into $\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}$", not "inserting $m = 1, 2$ or $3$ into $\sum_{m = 1}^3\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{k_{i+1}}{k_i}$". That doesn't even make sense, as $\sum_{m = 1}^3$ means "insert $m = 1, 2$ and $3$, and sum the respective results". I can't insert a value for $m$ in an expression which already tells me to insert different values for $m$.

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer well.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I added an example. Maybe that helps.

Comment: thank you. But, Is this answer needs to an explanation?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 What do you mean?

Comment: In your answer, 
As I understand it the summation symbol means how many terms and which term we have.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Yup. More specifically, it means _which_ terms we have. When we say $\sum_{m = 1}^3$, that means we get one term which corresponds to $m = 1$, one term which corresponds to $m = 2$ and one term which corresponds to $m = 3$, and then we add them all together. I wrote the $m = 2$ term in my answer above as an example.